# Should we specify the "private" label in c++ classes? Does it make any difference?

Tags: c++, class

This might not be the greatest question but since classes in c++ have all their attributes and methods by default private is there any point in specifying it?

Is it just a matter of preference? Does specifying the private part make the code look more or less proficient?

```
class User
{   
        string name;
        string surname;
        int miles;
        double balance; 

    public:
        User(string,string,int,double);

};
```

vs

```
class User
 {    
     private:
        string name;
        string surname;
        int miles;
        double balance; 

    public:
        User(string,string,int,double);

};
```

Comment: Preference, access specifier for classes is private by default (unlike struct)

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit. By default every method and attribute in a `class` will be `private` unless specified otherwise, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit about your intentions.

Comment: As @Borgleader said, it's a matter of preference.
But I always prefer the second case, except for structs where all the members and methods are public.

Comment: I prefer to have my private members follow the public members so in that case it is necessary to explicitly call them out.

Comment: Code styling guides (I guess none, covers this) - However, the second looks nicer.

Comment: @Borgleader: "structs" are classes too.

Comment: For some odd reason, Java promoted the idea to declare the least relevant part of a class — the privates — first. Most C++ programmers prefer to do the sensible thing and keep their private parts around the bottom, not immediately in your face.

Comment: @molbdnilo We do a similar thing (publics in your face, not privates). Also another idea in our coding standard (though this is always very subjective territory) is that the public parts should be more `stable`, static, non-changing. So if we imagine that things change over time, the private members may shrink or grow, but that keeps the rest of the code above from shifting around (maybe helping people to see a consistent, unchanging part of the code near the top that indicates how things are used). So we tend to look at these things not only in terms of what to emphasize in your face...

Comment: ... but also in terms of chaos and stability, with the assumption that privates can be more chaotic than publics, and with the idea that listing publics first keeps the top part of the header file more stable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit let's just embrace the pedantic for a moment, they are not the same, structs are structs and classes are classes. However, in practice, the function the same, except 'things' in classes are private by default and 'things' in structs are public by default.

Comment: @thecoshman: No, that is the polar opposite of true. Classes are classes are classes are classes. It's just that you can obtain one with the `class` keyword, or with the `struct` keyword (or with the `union` keyword), and which keyword you choose has an effect on how the symbols that make up your class definition are interpreted. Just to embrace the pedantic for a moment. Read chapter `[class]` of the C++ standard. Have fun!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's all stylistic and a matter of preference.

For example, in my team, we prefer to have publics before privates given that people generally read from top to bottom, and more people will be interested in how a class is *used* rather than how its *implemented* (like most people are interested in driving a car more than learning how a combustion engine works). So there we are forced into using `private` anyway given that we list those on the bottom, unless we used a `struct` where the default access is public (in which case we could omit the `public` specifier, but we typically don't use `structs` to save typing so much as to indicate simple aggregates of data).

But that's just how we roll. It's all up to you. Some may find the explicitness of seeing a `private` specifier beneficial to avoid mistakes in having to assume the default access of a `class`, e.g. It really varies on your team dynamics, what you want to emphasize, etc.

I think the only not-so-subjective aspect of a stylistic preference is that if there's one style that's superior, it's merely any style followed *consistently* by your team. If there's anything to ultimately achieve with a stylistic standard, it's merely that: *consistency*. This is especially true if you are publishing headers to the rest of the world (ex: as part of a software development kit). There you don't want each header to look like it was written by a completely independent person following a different set of standards. So sometimes a very 'exotic' standard with a lot of special rules and exceptions might be worth avoiding, no matter how arguably cool it is, if your team has a hard time consistently following it. Or they may not. It all depends.

Comment: That seems to become old school (Impact of IDE's, MSVC intellisense, ...)

Comment: @DieterLücking Yeah, we tend to look at those headers like documentation (but they're predominantly SDK headers used by people with a wide range of compilers, IDEs, etc). If you lean heavily on IDEs and possibly external doc generators like doxygen, then probably you could interleave public private private public all over the place and it wouldn't really matter that much.

Answer (score 3):

May increase readability. Some other language like java it have to explicit to make a class member `private`. Because there is a access modifier named `default` - when we don't write any access modifier before a class member. So it would be easier for those coming from other programming language to understand if we make explicit the access modifier - `private`. And of course it is a matter of preference in `C++`.

Answer (score 1):

**It is just a matter of preference.**

```
struct Foo
{
public:  // These are already public; no need to write it
    void a();
    int b;

private: // You need this one though
    char c;
};
```

Similarly:

```
class Bar
{
private: // These are already private; no need to write it
    void a();
    int b;

public:  // You need this one though
    char c;
};
```